# Complete number to specific length

Tags: linux, bash

I've a variable that contain a number, were `size(number) <= 10`
I want to "complete" that number to size 10.

For example:

```
num=123
num = complete(num)
#now num is '0000000123'

num=12345
num = complete(num)
#now num is '0000012345'

num=1234567891
num = complete(num)
#now num is '1234567891'
```

How do I do it?

Comment: last one (123457891) should become : 0123457891 ? (missing a "6")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `printf` to get 0 padded number

```
printf "%010d\n" $num
```

Answer (score 3):

```
num=$(echo "0000000000$num" | sed "s/.*\(..........\)/\1/")
```

In other words, you preprend 10 zeroes, then filter out the last 10 positions of the whole.

Answer (score 1):

```
function pad (str, max) {
  return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
}


pad("3", (10-pass your length of text box here));
```

See function works or not i don't have tested it

Check this link http://jsbin.com/epeVeYIC/1/edit